# How do I make different sessions on the site

Tags: session

I am using `session_start ();`
I want to make each page or each folder has its own session
Example: 
When you request mysite.com/A opens new session
When asked mysite.com/B opens new session

How so?

Comment: What do you mean by open new session? Do you mean to have different session variables on each of these pages?

Comment: I want these variables to be changed from one folder to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear as to what you mean by opening new session in each folder. If you meant to say that you want a session variable on each folder and the value of this variable should change from folder to folder:

Say, you have a session variable $_SESSION['folderName'] and you want to achieve:

$_SESSION['folderName'] = 'A'; // When in folder mysite.com/A

$_SESSION['folderName'] = 'B'; // When in folder mysite.com/B

Then you can do:

```js
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

//now when the URL is mysite.com/A, $segments[0] will
   // have mysite.com and $segments[1] will have 'A'

So, on each file on each folder, you can do:

<?
session_start();

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

$_SESSION['folderName'] = $segments[1];  
?>
```

Comment: Still retains sessions in all folders

Comment: Then on each of such folder try unsetting the session. unset($_SESSION); Not sure what you are needing to achieve here.

Comment: I can not cancel the appointment of the meeting I need to hearing
But each different from the other session
I've tried and I worked with some of the problems but

Comment: I am sorry I cannot get what you are trying to ask. Try posting some code snippets.